# Publishing scaffolded web site to azure

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, yeoman, gulp

I've used Steve Sanderson's [generator-ko](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-ko) for [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)

The image below shows the structure it creates:

[image: output from generator-ko]

Source code suitable for debugging is located in the **src** folder. [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) is used for building (minimizing, concatenation etc), and this output is placed in the **dist** folder.

So, down to business: What are my options for publishing this to Azure (web site)? The project will most likely be hosted on visual studio online, and I'd like to use the build system for nightly builds, running tests etc.

I've considered converting the project to an ASP.NET project, in order to utilize some of the features this provides (publishing etc), but I'm not sure if this is the best approach, or how to actually do this propely for that matter. For example, how should I deal with the fact that I've got a src folder and a dist folder, rather than a single web root?

I also want to utilize the test system (karma, jasmine) as part of the build process.

As you probably understand, I'm a bit clueless of where to go from here. How would you go about achieving what I've described here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to provide an answer for this myself, in case others wondering the same thing would happen to stumble upon this question:

After doing some digging I decided to create an Azure Web Sites set up with a local git repository, as described [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/)

I then used npm to install kudu-cli and used that to generate a .deployment script, as described [here](http://www.cptloadtest.com/2013/12/03/Git-And-Grunt-Deploy-To-Windows-Azure.aspx)

I then modified the script to install my bower modules and run my gulp script. Finally I modified the script so that only the content of the /dist folder was copied to the publish target folder.

In case others are as clueless as I was, the following information might be useful: The Azure Web Site hosting model is actually very straight forward. If you want to, you can easily just build locally and publish the /dist folder manually using ftp.

Update per request: Build script

```
@if "%SCM_TRACE_LEVEL%" NEQ "4" @echo off

:: ----------------------
:: KUDU Deployment Script
:: Version: 0.1.11
:: ----------------------

:: Prerequisites
:: -------------

:: Verify node.js installed
where node 2>nul >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment.
  goto error
)

:: Setup
:: -----

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET ARTIFACTS=%~dp0%..\artifacts

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.
)

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
)

IF NOT DEFINED NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH (
  SET NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest

  IF NOT DEFINED PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH (
    SET PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest
  )
)

IF NOT DEFINED KUDU_SYNC_CMD (
  :: Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  call npm install kudusync -g --silent
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: Locally just running "kuduSync" would also work
  SET KUDU_SYNC_CMD=%appdata%\npm\kuduSync.cmd
)
goto Deployment

:: Utility Functions
:: -----------------

:SelectNodeVersion

IF DEFINED KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD (
  :: The following are done only on Windows Azure Websites environment
  call %KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__nodeVersion.tmp" (
    SET /p NODE_EXE=<"%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__nodeVersion.tmp"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  )

  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__npmVersion.tmp" (
    SET /p NPM_JS_PATH=<"%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__npmVersion.tmp"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  )

  IF NOT DEFINED NODE_EXE (
    SET NODE_EXE=node
  )

  SET NPM_CMD="!NODE_EXE!" "!NPM_JS_PATH!"
) ELSE (
  SET NPM_CMD=npm
  SET NODE_EXE=node
)

goto :EOF

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------
:Deployment
echo Handling node.js deployment.

echo %DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%
echo %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%

echo 1. Select node version
call :SelectNodeVersion

echo 2. Install npm packages
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\package.json" (
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install 
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)

echo 3. Install bower packages
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\bower.json" (
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
  :: call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install bower
  call "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"/node_modules/.bin/bower install -g --config.interactive=false
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error 
  popd
)


:RELEASE
echo 4. Install and run gulp [RELEASE]
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\gulpfile.js" (
    pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
    call "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"/node_modules/.bin/gulp
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error 
    popd
)

echo 5. KuduSync [RELEASE]
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
    call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%/dist" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)
:EODEP

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: Post deployment stub
IF DEFINED POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION call "%POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION%"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

goto end

:: Execute command routine that will echo out when error
:ExecuteCmd
setlocal
set _CMD_=%*
call %_CMD_%
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%_CMD_%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:error
endlocal
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
endlocal
echo Finished successfully.
```

This is refrenced in the .deployment file

```
[config]
command = deploy.cmd
```

Comment: Can you share your .deployment script? i want to know how kudu launch your gulp file for minify files before run server.js

Comment: @JorgeGuerola I've updated my answer to your request

Comment: @havardhu, Did you get Karma/Jasmine working as part of the deployment? I'm trying to use Karma with PhantomJS on Azure during deployment but it's timing out.

Comment: @JamesThurley no I've not tried to set up karma yet, although it is in my todo pipeline

Comment: @havardhu In the end I found getting Azure to do all the grunt deployment tasks was a headache, so I used Travis CI instead.  I publish to GitHub, Travis CI picks it up and builds everything, runs Karma and Protractor tests, then publishes the dist folder back to another GitHub repository. Azure picks up that second repository and deploys it, with no custom deployment script required.

Comment: @JamesThurley interesting, I'll check it out!